# Overriding a property value in a Micronaut test

Tags: java, micronaut

Using `@Property` on a test method seems to not take effect.

This is my `application.yml`

```yaml
greeting: Hello
```

`Application.java`

```java
@Controller
public class Application {

    @Property(name = "greeting")
    String greeting;

    @Get
    String hello() {
        return greeting + " World!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Micronaut.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Now `test1` passes as expected, but `test2` fails.

```java
@MicronautTest//(rebuildContext = true)
public class DemoTest {

    @Inject
    @Client("/")
    HttpClient client;

    @Test
    void test1() {
        assertEquals(
                "Hello World!",
                client.toBlocking().retrieve(GET("/"))
        );
    }

    @Property(name = "greeting", value = "Bonjour")
    @Test
    void test2() {
        assertEquals(
                "Bonjour World!",
                client.toBlocking().retrieve(GET("/"))
        );
    }
}
```

Output

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <Bonjour World!> but was: <Hello World!>
```

If I used `rebuildContext = true`, the `HttpClient` is not re-configured with the new port, and the second test fails with:

```
Connect Error: Connection refused: no further information: localhost/127.0.0.1:[some random port]
```

I put this code on GitHub at https://github.com/salah3x/micronaut-test-property-override

Is this a bug or I'm missing something?

Comment: If you add `@Property(name = "greeting", value = "Bonjour")` to the test class (not method(s) within the test) does that affect either or both test methods for you?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Adding it to the test class affect both tests, so `test1` fails while `test2` passes

Comment: @JeffScottBrown is this something that has been fixed in Micronaut? I'm still facing it with 3.7.5 version

Comment: "is this something that has been fixed in Micronaut? " - I don't know.  TBH I didn't realize the annotation was supported on a per test method basis like that.

Comment: If your `Application` class that is marked with `@Refreshable` I would expect the test as written to pass.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that manually refreshing the `EmbeddedServer` combined with `@MicronautTest(rebuildContext = true)` makes the tests pass.

```java
@MicronautTest(rebuildContext = true)
public class DemoTest {

    @Inject
    @Client("/")
    HttpClient client;

    @Inject
    EmbeddedServer server;

    @Test
    void test1() {
        assertEquals(
                "Hello World!",
                client.toBlocking().retrieve(GET("/"))
        );
    }

    @Property(name = "greeting", value = "Bonjour")
    @Test
    void test2() {
        server.refresh();
        assertEquals(
                "Bonjour World!",
                client.toBlocking().retrieve(GET("/"))
        );
    }
}
```

But that's more of a workaround than a solution because the [docs](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-test/latest/guide/index.html#junit5) states that it should be automatically picked up.

Comment: Maybe an `@BeforeEach` setup-method to run `server.refresh()` before each test method is a viable option.